# How to trigger Django signal when using flush?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I'm using redis for caching data on my project and delete the cache through the signal. Whenever there is a change on my database the signal clear the cache using the key provided as follow:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Book)
def cache_clean_books(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    if created:
        cache.delete("all_books")
    else:
        cache.delete(f'book_id_{instance.id}')
```

Everything is working fine from here but when I use **python manage.py flush** to clear data from the database my signal is not triggered.
Is there any way I can use to hit the signal whenever I flush data in django please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `post_save` signal won't be called here since running `python manage.py flush` doesn't act on the model instance, it simply executes SQL to flush the database. You can use the [`post_migrate` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-migrate) if you want to run code whenever the `flush` command is run:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate


@receiver(post_migrate)
def clear_cache(sender, **kwargs):
    # Clear your cache here
    pass
```

**Note**: This will also run whenever you run a migration but I guess it can be safely assumed that a migration to the database should probably clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks I went through the documentation of post_migrate signal. That means I should use to clear all the cache when I flush the database.